# Launch PHP function when button is pressed

Tags: php, javascript

I have a php function that writes some text to a local file...

```
<?php
 function createtextfile() 
 {
 $file = fopen("test.txt","w");
echo fwrite($file,"Hello World. Testing!");
fclose($file);
}
?>
```

I am trying to launch this when a button is clicked but am not sure how best to go about it.  Would I need to use javascript or is there a way I can do it purely with PHP?

Comment: Try maybe `<input type='button' onclick='createtextfile();' value='Launch PHP function'/>`?

Comment: Javascript, or use a `<form>`

Comment: @Fred are you serious?

Comment: That code is executed on the server, and there is no way a user can execute code stuff on the serverside (at least not wihtout reloading the page), other than using ajax to call the script and execute the function.

Comment: @AustinBrunkhorst I said "maybe" lol

Comment: PHP is server side - there is no JavaScript interaction with PHP's functions.

Comment: You'd need Ajax for that button 'o mine to work.

Comment: @Fred i will not expect such an answer from a guy having 2105 reputation

Comment: @AustinBrunkhorst Hey Austin, you're getting a lot of upvotes! Going for the record today? hehehe

Comment: @KhawerZeshan Numbers mean nothing. Don't underestimate me Mr. 1333

Comment: @AustinBrunkhorst Hey **10**, lookah dat! and in bold, wow.

Comment: I don't see any of you who critisized me, giving any answers.

Comment: Wow, i've created a monster!

Comment: @fightstarr20 I love a good fight. hehe * grin * It gets the adrenaline going.

Comment: @fightstarr20 Theoretically, I was right about using a `button`. You can use Ajax in conjunction with either an `href` or `button`, while calling a function. The function itself will have the url to your .php code/file that you posted.

Comment: @fightstarr20 Something to the affect of (Ajax/JS) `function MakeRequest() { // code stuff xmlHttp.open("GET", "file.php", true); }` with the button `<input type='button' onclick='MakeRequest();' value='Activate function'/>`. **NOTE**: Yes I know there's a lot of code missing, but that's just a rough example.

Comment: @fightstarr20 You've gotten your code from >>> http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_filesystem_fwrite.asp undoubtedly. Don't use those. Everyone here calls them **W3 Fools**. I've given you a better example than most and you're not responding, so you're on your own now. **I am outta here**.

Comment: @AustinBrunkhorst I'll take back my "maybe" and say **"YES, I am."** I haven't seen any suggestions/answers on your part or anyone else who critisized me and upvoted your question to me. So, unless you've got an actual answer to give the OP, you've got nothing else to say. I, on the other hand, have given a crude yet "good" suggestion on how to use my **"Infamous BUTTON"**. All other answers here given below (SO FAR) have yet to add up to anything. So I say, phoque this, I am outta here.

Answer (score 3):

Move createfile to a new php file and call the php file with ajax

```
<a href="#" id="btn">Button</a>
<script>
    $("#btn").click(function(e) {
        $.ajax("createtextfile.php");
        e.stopPropagation();
        return false;
    });
</script>
```

and inside createfile.php

```
$file = fopen("test.txt","w");
fwrite($file,"Hello World. Testing!");
fclose($file);
```

Comment: Now you don't get the ugly `#` sign ;-)

Comment: I am getting '$ is not defined' error from my console attempting this method

Comment: @fightstarr20 Probably because of the **"echo"** in `echo fwrite($file,"Hello World. Testing!");`. Try removing it to read as `fwrite($file,"Hello World. Testing!");`

Comment: @fightstarr20 you have to include jquery

Comment: @Philipp Your `echoed` line shouldn't contain an `echo`. In order to echo the written content, would need to read as `echo file_get_contents("test.txt");` and not `echo fwrite($file,"Hello World. Testing!");`. Your above code will output **21**. I found that (your example) on **w3schools**, is that the example you gave the OP?

Comment: @Philipp Don't you want to call `e.preventDefault()` to prevent the `#` from being shown in URLs?

Comment: You can also just create a <button> with a name such as `<button name="mybutton">` and select it through jQuery like so `$("[name=myname]").click(function(e){ // ajax call here    e.preventDefault(); });`

Answer (score 1):

You can do it purely using PHP and HTML if you make the button part of a form, and send POST / GET variables, then look for them in the PHP script;

```
i.e.

<?php
  if($_POST['submit'] == "Push Button!"){
    //Do whatever  
  }else{
    //Show the regular webpage.
?>

<form id="someForm" method="POST">
  <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Push Button!">
</form>

<?php
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Pretend you are making an HTML form and have your php be the action called on submit.

Answer (score 0):

if you use a form it becomes really easy

your html would look something like

```
<form method="GET/POST" action="yourphpscript.php">

whatever you wanna include in the form

<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit"/>

</form>
```

then using php you can do what you need to, once you find out the button is clicked

```
<?php

      if(isset($_POST['submit']))
      {
            do what you wanna do in here
      }

?>
```

This is the php way of doing things, not too sure about javascript

Hope this helps.